# I have A grid Vied and I wand to insert grid row details to a new table when i'm uploading files through the grid in ASP.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sql-server

I looked for many solutions in google. I couldn't find out a solution. I have a grid view In my asp.net template this image

[image: [Grid in ASP.net]]

After submiting a file, i want to set submited file raw details to a new table in database. this is that table

[image: [New tanle that need to be updated after submiting]]

(I am new for this subject)

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public partial class Assignments : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["ID"].ToString();
        DBL.AddAssignment obj12 = new DBL.AddAssignment();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR12 = null;
        sqlDR12 = obj12.Getbatchofstudent(Session["ID"].ToString().Trim());
        while(sqlDR12.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text=sqlDR12[9].ToString().Trim();
        }

        String BID = Label1.Text;
        DBL.AddAssignment obj = new DBL.AddAssignment();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = null;
        sqlDR = obj.Viewassignmentingrid(BID);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grid1.DataSource = sqlDR;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }

        
    }



    protected void grid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void grid1_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void grid1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bts = e.CommandSource as Button;
        Response.Write(bts.Parent.Parent.GetType().ToString());
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "upload")
        {
            return;
        }
        FileUpload fu = bts.FindControl("FileUpload4") as FileUpload;//here
        if (fu.HasFile)
        {
            bool upload = true;
            string fleUpload = Path.GetExtension(fu.FileName.ToString());
            if (fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xls" | fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            {
                fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
                string uploadedFile = (Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
                //Someting to do?...
            }
            else
            {
                upload = false;
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Sorry, Your file didn't uploaded to the server. Try again. Make sure that your are uploading .Docx or .Doc files');</script>");
                // Something to do?...
            }
            if (upload)
            {
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Your file has been successfully uploaded to the server. Thank you');</script>");

            }
        }
    }

    protected void grid1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //int index = e.RowIndex;

        //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grid1.Rows[index];

        //Label AssignmentID = (Label)row.FindControl("LblASGNID");
        //Label AssignmentName = (Label)row.FindControl("LblCASGNName");
        //Label Coursename = (Label)row.FindControl("LblCourseName");
        //Label BatchID = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelBatch");
        //Label SubjectID = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubID");
        //Label Subjectname = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubname");
        //Label Submissiondate = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubdate");
        //DateTime Submiteddate= DateTime.Now;

        //FileUpload fu = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("fu1");

        //if (fu.HasFile)
        //{

        //    DBL.AddAssignment obj12 = new DBL.AddAssignment();
        //    SqlDataReader sqlDR12 = null;
        //    sqlDR12 = obj12.Getbatchofstudent(Session["ID"].ToString().Trim());
        //    while (sqlDR12.Read())
        //    {
        //        Session["ID2"] = sqlDR12[0].ToString().Trim();
        //    }

        //    //string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/"), fu.FileName);
        //    //fu.SaveAs(file);
        //    {
        //        DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails obj = new DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails();
        //        obj.SID1 = Session["ID2"].ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.AssignmentID1 = AssignmentID.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.Assignmentname1 = AssignmentName.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.Coursename1 = Coursename.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.BatchID = BatchID.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.SubjectID1 = SubjectID.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.SubjectName1 = Subjectname.ToString().Trim();
        //        obj.SubmissionDate1 = DateTime.Parse(Submissiondate.ToString());
        //        obj.SubmitedDate1 = Submiteddate;
        //        obj.UploadAssignment(obj);
        //    }

        //}

        //SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Employee set EmpName='" + ename.Text + "',EmpEmailId='" + emid.Text + "',EmpMobileNum=" + Convert.ToInt64(mnumber.Text) + "", con);
        //con.Open();
        //int res1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //con.Close();

        //if (res1 == 1)
        //{
        //    Response.Write("<script>alert('Updation done!')</script>");
        //}
        //gv1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind();
    }
}
```

```html
**This is ASP.NET cooding**

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Assignment Upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignments" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <title>Student Profile</title>

    <!-- ============ Google fonts ============ -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300,800'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <!-- ============ CSS here ============ -->
    <link href="css/1bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/1font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="images/logonuwana.png" style="background-color:transparent"  width="60" height="60"/></td>
                        <td><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-size:medium" >Nuwana School Student Information System</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="HOME.aspx">Home</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width:1000px">
            <div class="registrationform">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Student Profile <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%--2016.01.18--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="col-lg-2 control-label"></asp:Label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10" style="width:600px">
                                <asp:Label ID="StudentNo" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control" Font-Names="AmericanTypewriter-Light" ForeColor="#66FF66" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="False" AlternatingRowStyle-Wrap="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="False" EditIndex="-1" SelectedIndex="-1" UseAccessibleHeader="True" OnDisposed="grid1_Disposed" OnRowCommand="grid1_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="grid1_RowUpdating" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid1_SelectedIndexChanged">  
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />  
     <columns>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assignment Name">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblCASGNName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Assignmetname") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assignment ID">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblASGNID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("AssignmentID") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course Name">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblCourseName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("CourseName") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LabelBatch" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("BatchID") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject Name">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblSubname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("SubjectName") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject ID">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblSubID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("SubjectID") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issued Date">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblIssueddate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Issueddate") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField>  
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submission Date">  
             <ItemTemplate>  
                 <asp:Label ID="LblSubdate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Submissiondate") %>'></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>  
         </asp:TemplateField> 
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Logo Upload">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="bt_upload" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="Upload" CommandName="Upload" Height="22" Width="120" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
     </columns>  
     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />  
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
     <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />  
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />  
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />  
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />  
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />  
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />  
 </asp:GridView>     
                        </div>
                       <%-- <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Next" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />                              
                            </div>
                        </div>--%>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/1jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/1bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';


        $.backstretch(
        [

            "images/44.jpg",

        ],

        {
            duration: 4500,
            fade: 1500
        }
    );
    </script>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks good. What happen when you click on upload button. Did you debug it and check? Is there any error occurred?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, File is uploading to the directory. It is okay. But no values are going to the database.. I want to get the values of the row which I'm uploading file and add those details to a new table. That is not happening with this coding..

Comment: I see that you just save file within rowcommand event. Not updating anything in database.

Comment: See the commented codes. I wrote it to update table. it is not working I think

Comment: Well, placed it within rowcommand event, along with file save code. So first save file, get filename and save that filename in database.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help Piyush Khatri. I found out a way to do it. Here it is.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public partial class Assignments : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["ID"].ToString();
        DBL.AddAssignment obj12 = new DBL.AddAssignment();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR12 = null;
        sqlDR12 = obj12.Getbatchofstudent(Session["ID"].ToString().Trim());
        while(sqlDR12.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text=sqlDR12[9].ToString().Trim();
        }

        String BID = Label1.Text;
        DBL.AddAssignment obj = new DBL.AddAssignment();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = null;
        sqlDR = obj.Viewassignmentingrid(BID);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grid1.DataSource = sqlDR;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }

        
    }

    protected void grid1_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void grid1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bts = e.CommandSource as Button;
        Response.Write(bts.Parent.Parent.GetType().ToString());
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "upload")
        {
            return;
        }
        FileUpload fu = bts.FindControl("FileUpload4") as FileUpload;//here
        if (fu.HasFile)
        {
            bool upload = true;
            string fleUpload = Path.GetExtension(fu.FileName.ToString());
            if (fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xls" | fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            {
                //Someting to do?...
                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grid1.Rows[rowIndex];
                Label AssignmentID = (Label)row.FindControl("LblASGNID");
                Label AssignmentName = (Label)row.FindControl("LblCASGNName");
                Label Coursename = (Label)row.FindControl("LblCourseName");
                Label BatchID = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelBatch");
                Label SubjectID = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubID");
                Label Subjectname = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubname");
                Label Submissiondate = (Label)row.FindControl("LblSubdate");
                DateTime Submiteddate = DateTime.Now;

                FileUpload fu1 = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload4");
                if (fu1.HasFile)
                {
                    DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails objf = new DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails();
                    SqlDataReader sqlDRf = null;
                    sqlDRf = objf.GetcourseID(Session["ID"].ToString().Trim(), AssignmentID.Text.ToString());
                    if (sqlDRf.Read())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Your assignment For this subject has been already submited');</script>");
                        upload = false;
                    }

                    else if (Convert.ToDateTime(Submissiondate.Text.ToString()) < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Sorry Your Submission Date is Over');</script>");
                        upload = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DBL.AddAssignment obj12 = new DBL.AddAssignment();
                        SqlDataReader sqlDR12 = null;
                        sqlDR12 = obj12.Getbatchofstudent(Session["ID"].ToString().Trim());
                        while (sqlDR12.Read())
                        {
                            Session["ID2"] = sqlDR12[0].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails obj = new DBL.Assignmentuploadeddetails();
                        obj.SID1 = Session["ID2"].ToString().Trim();
                        obj.AssignmentID1 = AssignmentID.Text;
                        obj.Assignmentname1 = AssignmentName.Text;
                        obj.Coursename1 = Coursename.Text;
                        obj.BatchID = BatchID.Text;
                        obj.SubjectID1 = SubjectID.Text;
                        obj.SubjectName1 = Subjectname.Text;
                        obj.SubmissionDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Submissiondate.Text.ToString());
                        obj.SubmitedDate1 = Submiteddate;
                        obj.UploadAssignment(obj);

                        fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
                        string uploadedFile = (Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                upload = false;
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Sorry, Your file didn't uploaded to the server. Try again. Make sure that your are uploading .Docx or .Doc files');</script>");
                // Something to do?...
            }
            if (upload)
            {
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Your file has been successfully uploaded to the server. Thank you');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
    protected void bt_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void grid1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```